# Not able to activate MySQL database and PHP in XAMPP.

Tags: php, mysql

- Here in localhost I can see that MySQL database and PHP component status is DEACTIVATED.
- And in XAMPP control panel it's Started.

So, I'm not able to use the PHP and MySQL database properly. Can't access the database.

PS: I just started PHP programming.

Answer (score 0):

1. Suggest that you check the MySQL DB status in command line.
2. Check the php log.